# In App Purchase Can't buy more then 10 items at once

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

When I've tested IAP in Sandbox mode get error. What is mean and how to fix it

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just wondering how you doing multiple in-app purchase at a time ?

Comment: @Deeps [quantity](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPayment/quantity)

Comment: @FilipRadelic cool thanks. I haven't used that yet. Great to know.

Comment: what is purpose of In app purchase in your app? So we can help you which kind of and how you implement it.

Comment: I sell area. Minimal area 10x10 = 1$ - Maximal 100x100 = 100$. User can get area in range of it values at once. I added buy multiple items this code: - (void)purchaseItems:(NSUInteger)items
{
    SKMutablePayment *payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId];
    payment.quantity = items;
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

Comment: @iSemic Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Make smaller "packs".

For example:

- 1 widget
- Pack of 10 widgets
- Pack of 50 widgets

Comment: I can't do it! I need exactly one item = one price. Sell multiple items at once...